# How to set SCSS variable value programatically in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am working on a project in `ReactJS`. I have to create multiple themes feature in this website. Color code of all themes are coming from an API.

I have used variables in SCSS and imported them throughout the project to set color. For example

```
$primary-color: #fec00b;
```

but now I need to set value of that `primary-color` dynamically using color code that I am receiving in API response.

So how I can set it programatically?

Comment: I did this once by injecting a style tag into the document. The API was returning a stylesheet as plain text and by `document.createElement('style')` I was injecting. You can then use global to check if the style is present and conditionaly read that or use default theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change values dynamically then `SASS` it is not suitable for this task, because of it should be compiled into `CSS` before it can be used by browser.

It is much more better to use native css variables for such tasks - they are dynamic, you could change them any time both from `css` and from `js`. And browser support is also very good (unless you must support IE).

Here's a little example of how to change such vars:

```js
let $color = document.querySelector('#color');

$color.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let color = e.target.value;
  document.querySelector("html").style.setProperty('--box-bg', color);
})
```

```css
html {
  --box-bg: gold;
}

.box {
  background: var(--box-bg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>

<label>
  Choose color
  <input type='color' id='color' />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I create this custom hook:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { camelToKebab } from '../utils/strings'

const useGlobalVariables = (className = 'global', styles = {}) => {
  const setVariable = (variable, value) => {
    document.querySelector('html').style.setProperty(variable, value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(styles).forEach(([property, value]) => {
      setVariable(`--${className}-${camelToKebab(property)}`, value)
    })
  }, [])
}

export default useGlobalVariables

/**
 * Usage
 * Component:
 * useGlobalVariables('styled-modal', {
 *   maxWidth,
 *   width,
 *   height,
 *   maxHeight,
 *   overflow,
 * })
 * CSS:
 * .class-name {
 *   width: var(--class-name-width);
 *   height: var(--class-name-height);
 *   max-width: var(--class-name-max-width) !important;
 *   max-height: var(--class-name-max-height) !important;
 *   overflow: auto !important;
 * }
 */
```

Unit tests:

```js
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useGlobalVariables from './useGlobalVariables'

describe('useGlobalVariables', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // remove global variables
    document.querySelector('html').removeAttribute('style')
  })

  it('should set global variables', () => {
    const styles = {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      fontSize: '16px',
    }

    renderHook(() => useGlobalVariables('global', styles))

    expect(
      document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue(
        '--global-background-color',
      ),
    ).toBe('red')
    expect(
      document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--global-font-size'),
    ).toBe('16px')
  })

  it('should convert property names to kebab-case', () => {
    const styles = {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      fontFamily: 'Arial',
    }

    renderHook(() => useGlobalVariables('custom', styles))

    expect(
      document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue(
        '--custom-background-color',
      ),
    ).toBe('red')
    expect(
      document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--custom-font-family'),
    ).toBe('Arial')
  })

  it('should not set variables if styles object is empty', () => {
    renderHook(() => useGlobalVariables())

    expect(document.documentElement.style.cssText).toBe('')
  })
})
```